# Cannot import { getStorage } from firebase/storage to use with React Native Expo image picker

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I am trying to get an image picker to save to Firebase. I've read a number of tutorials as well as the official documentation for Google cloud storage. They all say to do something like this:

```
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";
```

so you can:

```
const storage = getStorage()
```

and then

```
const ref = firebase.storage().ref();
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get anything but this error:

> TypeError: (0, _storage.getStorage) is not a function. (In '(0, _storage.getStorage)()', '(0, _storage.getStorage)' is undefined)

I can see firebase/storage in my node_modules. I console-logged (firebase) to make sure it is a thing. I tried a million different kinds of import. I installed other firebase dependencies like @react-native-firebase to use their storage functions, but nothing is working. Everything else Firebase works fine for me.

I have no clue what the problem is. I would be happy to do it another way, but everything says to use the storage() method. Am I doing something wrong? Is there an alternative to using the storage method to upload images to the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of Firebase you have in your app.

Firebase version 8 uses the `firebase.storage()` method.

In order to use `getStorage` you need to use Firebase v9.x

See this guide on how to upgrade:
[Upgrade from version 8 to the modular Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)

For Version 8, make sure to click on the Web Version 8 tab in the Firebase Docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Here is a snippet of code that worked for me (Firebase V8).

My Firebase Initialization File: FirebaseInitialize.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/storage";

import { firebaseConfig } from "./firebaseConfig";

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export { firebase };
```

My Firebase Config file

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "YOUR-API-KEY",
  authDomain: "YOUR-DOMAIN.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://YOUR-DOMAIN.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "YOUR-PROJECTID",
  storageBucket: "YOUR-SOTRAGEBUCKET.appspot.com",
  appId: "APP-ID",
};
```

Where I need to use storage, this is what I do this:

```
import { firebase } from "./FirebaseInitialize";

const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

storageRef.put(file).then((snapshot) => {
  console.log("Uploaded!");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using version 8(.2.3) because 9 was breaking everything. Does the storage() method need to be imported from firebase or firebase/storage or something else? I'll try anything at this point.

Comment: When you go through the documents, make sure to click on the "Web Version 8" tab.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

I'll edit my answer to include the code that made it work for me.

Comment: It's still not working but I marked your answer correct because I think it has all of the elements that I will need to get it working when I find the time to upgrade to Firebase 9. I appreciate your time and hope other people find this helpful

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. The code is in V8, I have updated my answer to include the config files and also all the import statements to help make it all work.

Answer (score 1):

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"; 
import "firebase/storage";
```

worked for me
make sure you use firebase version < 9

```
const handleUpload = async (pic) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(pic)
        const blob = await response.blob()
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        // storageRef.put(blob).then((snapshot) => {
        //     console.log("Uploaded!");
        // });
        let ref = storageRef.child("/images/" + decoded.id)
        return ref.put(blob)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```